# How do I enumerate the items in beamer table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm inserting a `\tableofcontents` slide in my beamer presentation. The trouble is that I have everything in `itemize` environment throughout my presentation. (Gives a better view to the audience.) The Table of Contents, however appears without the itemization/enumeration. Can the entries in `tableofcontents` be itemized? I can't find an option in `beamer` manual or online to this effect.

Here's my current table of contents:

```
\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[section,subsection]
\end{frame}
```

p.s. I'm also using the `\AtBeginSection` overlays so those have to change as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adapted from the [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section 10.5:

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
%\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball unnumbered]
%\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[ball unnumbered]
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[section,subsection]
\end{frame}
\section{One}
\begin{frame}
Some content
\end{frame}
\subsection{Alpha}
\begin{frame}
Some content
\end{frame}
\section{Two}
\begin{frame}
Some content
\end{frame}
\subsection{Beta}
\begin{frame}
Some content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks. Guess I didn't know what to search for in the manual.

Comment: Also added another option as another answer. Accepted your answer though as it fully explains the actual question.

Answer (score 12):

For future reference, I'm putting a detailed answer as well that gives more power. If you want something more complicated than the `ball` and `square` templates for this, you can redefine the template like so:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
    *  \inserttocsection \par}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{
    -- \inserttocsubsection \par}
```

Comment: For anyone interested you can reproduce the accepted answer with this answer using `\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber`, e.g., to generate: `1.1`